# IE adding http header PRAGMA: no-cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, ssl, httpresponse

I am currently developing a site using SSL that requires users to be able to upload files of different types (such as excel or word files) and then each item will be added to a grid.  The user can then "click" on the the item in the grid and the item they uploaded would be displayed.  The problem I am running into is with Internet Explorer adding the Pragma: "no-cache" header to the response which is blocking the user from viewing/saving the file if it is a file that has a content type with "application/~".  When I try to do something like

```
Response.Headers.Remove("Pragma");
```

I get this error: 
*This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.*
Can anyone help me understand what is causing this and what I need to do to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HttpResponse.Headers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx) property:

> The Headers property is only supported with the IIS 7.0 integrated pipeline mode and at least the .NET Framework 3.0. When you try to
>   access the Headers property and either of these two conditions is not
>   met, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown.

A solution from here: [“This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode”](http://thepursuitofalife.com/this-operation-requires-iis-integrated-pipeline-mode/)

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=enrollments.csv");
Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
```

Comment: Ok great I will give that a try.  When you use Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public"); and there is already a Pragma header, does it just replace the previous header?

Comment: To answer my own question "The AddHeader method adds a new HTML header and value to the response sent to the client. It does not replace an existing header of the same name. After a header has been added, it cannot be removed. "  So I don't know how this is going to work but testing it can't hurt (I just first have to get permission to publish this out to our dev environment)

Comment: What I am reading says it won't change it, but I haven't tested any code.

Comment: Side note, if you have a caching issue, add a unique query-string variable to your url and or file name to force the browser to serve it up.  I use DateTime.Now.Ticks all the time.

Comment: No these aren't really caching issues, its just about SSL adding a no-cache policy that is blocking the user from viewing certain files